# signature pads (Wacom ?)

Tags: wacom, signature

Is the signing of sheets on signature pads supported under Ubuntu ?

In our shop, this is a widespread use case and it's currently based on Windows

Is an equivalent solution available under Ubuntu ?

It doesn't have to be based on Wacom products, it could be any vendor, as long as it works

Comment: It might help if you let us know which models of signature pads you are referring to. Wacom tablets are supported in Ubuntu since quite a few years. https://askubuntu.com/questions/284284/wacom-tablet-support-in-ubuntu

Comment: a Wacom stu 530 and a Wacom stu 430, for now

Comment: if these models are not ocmpatible with ubuntu, I'd be happy with the suggestion of any model (even not Wacom) that is compatible

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi

Comment: It looks like it. The easiest way to test is to use a Live USB/DVD and see if they work - but it looks like they do. They've even got an SDK for Linux, from some searching.

Comment: @KGIII I can't find their sdk, can you point me to it, please ?

Comment: I didn't save it, as I figured you'd find it or just test it. Root around [here](https://developer.wacom.com/en-us/products/wacom-ink-sdk-for-signature).